# Check for recordtypes and based on that clone cases

Tags: apex, schedulebatch

Want to check If record Type is A or B or C or D then only clone cases. What changes will have to be done ?

**Batch Apex**

```
    public class Account_CloneCasesOnAnniversary implements Database.Batchable<SObject>
    {
       String errors = '';
       integer todayday = date.today().day();
       Integer currentmonth = date.today().month();
       List<Task> taskCreateList = new List<Task>();
       Map<Id,Case> clonedCasesMap = new Map<Id,Case>();

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
       return Database.getQueryLocator('SELECT Anniversary__c,(Select Id,OwnerId from cases order by CreatedDate),Id from Account WHERE DAY_IN_MONTH(Anniversary__c) =:todayday AND CALENDAR_MONTH(Anniversary__c ) =: currentmonth');
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Account> scope) {

    Id Activation_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Activation_Action_Plan').getRecordTypeId();

    Id Master_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Master_Action_Plan').getRecordTypeId();

    Id NSCHBC_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('NSCHBC_Action_Plan').getRecordTypeId();

    Id Total_Core_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Total_Core_Action_Plan').getRecordTypeId();

     if(scope.isEmpty()) return;

        for(Account account : scope) {
           if(account.cases!=null && account.cases.size() > 0) {
                list<Case> lstCase = new list<Case>();
                for(Case objcase : account.cases){
                **if(objcase.RecordTypeId == Activation_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId || objcase.RecordTypeId == Master_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId || objcase.RecordTypeId ==NSCHBC_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId || objcase.RecordTypeId ==Total_Core_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId)**{ 
                    Case cloneCase = new Case();
                    cloneCase  = objcase.clone();
                    clonedCasesMap.put(objcase.Id,cloneCase);
                    }

                 if(objcase.RecordTypeId == Master_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId){ 
                    Case cloneCase = new Case();
                    cloneCase  = objcase.clone();
                    clonedCasesMap.put(objcase.Id,cloneCase);
                    }

                if(objcase.RecordTypeId == NSCHBC_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId){ 
                    Case cloneCase = new Case();
                    cloneCase  = objcase.clone();
                    clonedCasesMap.put(objcase.Id,cloneCase);
                    }

                if(objcase.RecordTypeId == Total_Core_Action_Plan_RecordTypeId){ 
                    Case cloneCase = new Case();
                    cloneCase  = objcase.clone();
                    clonedCasesMap.put(objcase.Id,cloneCase);
                    }   


                }
            }
        }

        if(!clonedCasesMap.isEmpty()) {
            Database.SaveResult[] srList = Database.insert(clonedCasesMap.values(), false);
            Integer index = 0;

            for(Database.SaveResult result : srList ) {
                if(!result.isSuccess()) {
                    String errMsg = result.getErrors()[0].getMessage();
                } 
                index++;
            }
        }

    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the Id of each record type using DeveloperName of record type and and then compare the Case Recordtype to clone the Case according to different conditions.

Note- You need to retrieve RecordTypeId of Case while querying Case records.

```
Id A_RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('A').getRecordTypeId();

Id B_RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('B').getRecordTypeId();

Id C_RecordTypeId = Schema.SObjectType.Case.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('C').getRecordTypeId();

for(Account account : scope) {
        if(account.cases.size() > 0) {
            list<Case> lstCase = new list<Case>();
            for(Case objcase : account.cases){
                if(objcase.RecordTypeId == A_RecordTYpeId){
                    // Clone According to the condition
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Made the changes in my code. Is it right ?

Comment: As you are comparing it for four record type ids, you can put them in one single condition and separate by "OR" operator.

Comment: Getting an error : attempt to de-refernce a null object. Made the changes but no luck yet. Also, updated the code for your refernce

Comment: Seems, you have not queried the record type id field of Case object in start method.

Comment: N.B. Devendra -- `getRecordTypeInfosByName` yields a map of recordtypes by label, not developerName. Something that has tripped me up in the past. See Idea https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000K9zoAAC

Comment: @cropredy Thank you for this information. I earlier thought, it is using DeveloperName.